# send data bad format when using pathValue in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I creating the editing form in Angular 6.

When page I loaded it set value with this code :

```
this.editFG.patchValue({
  productTitle: [data.productTitle],
  productName: [data.productName],
  color: [data.color],
  price: [data.price],
  gurantyMonth: [data.gurantyMonth],
  gurantyCompanyName: [data.gurantyCompanyName],
  catId: [data.catId],
  brandId: [data.brandId]
})
```

and when I need to send data from the server it sends data with this format :

```
color: ["999"]
gurantyCompanyName: ["999"]
gurantyMonth: ["999"]
price: [999]
productImageName: "999.jpg"
productName: ["999"]
productTitle: ["999"]
```

and server shows me an error:

> Bad Request

Now I need to send data without this `[]` i need send like this: `productTitle: "999"`.

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You see what you are doing for example with: `productTitle:[data.productTitle],` You are inserting `data.productTitle` in an array, so what your server gets is correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the name of the controls on your FormGroup and the name of the keys on the data is the same doing just this would suffice:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  editFG: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.editFG = this.fb.group({
      productTitle:[null],
      productName:[null],
      color:[null],
      price:[null],
      gurantyMonth:[null],
      gurantyCompanyName:[null],
      catId:[null],
      brandId:[null]
    });

    this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.editFG.patchValue(data);
        console.log('Here\'s the form value', this.editFG.value);
      });
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-value-patch-value-and-then-get-value?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: no i can not using this way . please show me other way

Comment: @Mr-Programer, like I said, patchValue will try to set the values of the controls as better as it can. So it will only set the values that are available there on the form and will only set the keys that correspond to them on the response object. So again, doing just `this.editFG.patchValue(data);` would set the form value for you. And once you get the form value like `this.editFG.value` you would get the form's value properly. (NOT EACH ONE AS AN ARRAY)